# Can I add iOS simulators from old Xcode 6.4 to new Xcode 7 without downloading?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, ios9, xcode7

I have installed new `Xcode 7.0` which showing `ios 9.0` simulator alone.

Already my `Xcode 6.4` had iOS version 7.1 and 8 series simulators.

How can I add the simulators from my old `Xocde 6.4` to new `Xocde 7` without downloading.

Please help me out this..

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the necessary simulators in each version of Xcode separately. Use Xcode -> Preference -> Downloads option.

Also iOS 7.x simulators not available for Xcode 7

It allows only to copy simulators from one machine to another machine for same Xcode versions

[Ref](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/83434/copy-simulator-from-one-mac-to-another-mac-osx)

Comment: For previous versions I have copied from old Xcode. Why this xcode dosen't support that?